# ISO-8859-1 decode vb.net

Tags: vb.net, iso-8859-1

I'm having problems decoding a file with "ISO-8859-1" encoding.
For example, I can't decode "%E7" to "ç". Can you help me?

P.S.: I'm using VB.NET

Thanks,
Pedro

Answer (score 1):

%E7 is not a string that's encoded in 8859-1.  It looks like URL encoding.  Use HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))